# Git hook to indicate repository is deprecated

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

We have a repository (hosted on a GitLab instance) which a handful of projects still reference, but has been deprecated in favor of another solution.

Is there any way to mark a repository as "deprecated"?

Ideally, every *fetch* from this repository (as part of a `git submodule update`) would cause a giant message to be printed during the fetch. I was expecting to add a simple Git hook that would print this deprecated message. However, there [doesn't seem to be](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) a "run this on every fetch" hook.

Also, I see nothing in GitLab that would enable this.

Comment: Won't the "post-checkout" and/or "post-merge" hooks cover the situations you need?

Comment: Deleting or renaming/relocating the repository would cause every fetch from that repository to fail in a rather obvious way...

Comment: @Waylan Those are locally-installed, no? I want a hook on the remote server that complains.

Comment: @twalberg Yes, I'd considered that, but I don't want things to fail to work (yet). I want to make a smooth transition to the new solutions.

Comment: As I see it there is currently no way to realize this with the tools git provides you. Maybe you could add a bounch of `THIS REPOSITORY IS DEPRECATED` files?

Comment: What about changing access rules to deprecated repositories in Gitlab? Explicitly allow access for projects that already reference a deprecated repository and deny access for everybody else.

Comment: @nils "Project" == "Repository". Project access rules apply to users. This doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Similar question (not gitlab related, just git): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659916/git-remote-show-a-custom-message-at-every-clone-fetch

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab has feature called "Broadcast messages" [since 6.3](https://about.gitlab.com/2013/11/21/gitlab-ce-6-dot-3-released/).  On the [screenshot](http://arche.depotoi.re/autoblogs/bloggitlaborg_95837ddb777820b3680c99552b35b1895026dae9/media/d8fe94fc.broadcast-show.png) they shows message with the same color as header and many users could simply not notice it.

However, it is possible to choose color for these messages [since 6.5](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/CHANGELOG).  For example, administrators at my work once made blue message and it was very hard not to notice the message.

So you may

- Make bright and visible broadcast message telling that this instance of Gitlab is deprecated and that everyone should use something else because at day X write access will be closed.
- At day X make everyone read-only.
- Leave this instance of Gitlab so old links won't be broke and so on.

Comment: It's not the entire GitLab instance I'm deprecating. It's just specific libraries, which are their own repository/project on GitLab.

Comment: The link with anchor text "screenshot" is broken.

Comment: The broadcast message will only be shown in the GUI, not on every fetch and not on fetch for a specific repo, right?