# Git Remote: Show a Custom Message, at Every Clone/Fetch?

Tags: git

Is it possible to configure a git remote repo in such a way that everytime someone fetches it or pushes something, a custom message is displayed?

My intention is to give  information about the branch structure. 
So in a way a light version of a git request-pull.

```
#git fetch
Welcome to projectx... commit your experimental changes @beta,
the more or less stable features @dev.
The stable and the testing branch will be maintained by "Mastermind"
```

Thats what I imagine.
Is this possible? I've got full rights to the remote repo.

Comment: Use your README for that

Comment: Well, that was an option. But people need to read it. By connecting it to git directly I hope to enforce this.

Comment: A use case I see is if I did something like introduce a new dependency and I want anyone who pulls those commits to be told they need to install that dependency

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can find is the [uploadpack.packObjectsHook](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-uploadpackpackObjectsHook) config option. There you can specify a script which should print the message to the standard error and call git-upload-pack with same arguments.

I did not try if it works.