# Disable git repository but provide explanation on clones and pulls

Tags: git

I have a remote git repository that various people pull from using ssh. I would like to disable the git repository but provide some sort of friendly explanation whenever there is a git clone or git pull. For example, "This git repository is no longer being maintained. Please use the repository at XYZ in the future".

Is there a (relatively) easy way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git hook to indicate repository is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982089/git-hook-to-indicate-repository-is-deprecated)

Comment: Unfortunately Git does not have a hook for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are [not using GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31184290/6309), and its broadcast message feature, then you could make [ssh calls a forced command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309) which would:

- check which url is requested
- display your message for a specific repo
- transfer to the actual git command for any other repo.

That supposes you do control the server which hosts the remote repo accessed through ssh.